# Bernoulli random variables and correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, correlation, binomial-distribution

Let's consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ following a Bernoulli distribution such that:
$$
P(X=1) = p\\
P(Y=1) = q
$$
The correlation coefficient $\rho$ is given and my goal is to compute $P(X \cap Y)$:
$$
\rho = \frac{E[XY]-E[X] E[Y]}{\sqrt{Var(X)*Var(Y)}} = \frac{P(X\cap Y)-pq}{\sqrt{p\cdot (1-p) \cdot q\cdot (1-q)}} \\
P(X \cap Y) = \rho \cdot \sqrt{p \cdot (1-p) \cdot q\cdot (1-q)} + pq\\
$$
When $X$ and $Y$ and perfectly anti-correlated, $\rho = -1$ and I expect to have $P(X \cap Y)=0$.
But a quick numerical application taking $p=q=\frac{1}{1000}$ gives:
$$
P(X \cap Y)=-0.000999
$$
What am I missing?

Comment: You have proven that two such distributions cannot be perfectly anticorrelated.  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160669/919 I proved generally, for any two finite-variance random variables $X$ and $Y,$ that perfect anticorrelation implies $X$ and $Y$ must be linearly related (with a negative coefficient): but this is impossible unless $p=1-q.$

Comment: Indeed that makes sense now.

Comment: The general principle that whuber is illustrating is known as the Frechet-Hoeffding bounds. The marginal distributions of two random variables impose some (weak) constraints on the joint distribution, that prevents examples like the one you presented.